# Recovering data of an formatted ext4 partition

Tags: data-recovery

An ext4 partition of Hard Disk is formatted to ext2 and then again to ext4 using GParted. Is there a way to recover the original data?

I want to reconver .webm files. I could not do this with testdisk.

Comment: try to find backup partition tables with `wipefs`. do `man wipefs` for info. and stop formatting disks you don't want to format!

Comment: testdisk, or more specifically photorec, is your best bet here. it supports webm files - but it only works well for unfragmented data.

Comment: @frostschutz: Is there a way to search for .webm files with testdisk instaed of all files?

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally formatted an ext4 partition to NTFS in my Ubuntu 16.04 recently and was able to recover the full partition successfully by running a file system check.

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda10
```

I recorded the steps in [this blog post](https://notebookbft.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/recovering-accidentally-formatted-ext4-partition-fixing-superblock/#more-710). However note that the scenario is a bit different from the question.